# Agora.io Analytics

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, agora.io

I am using Agora Analytics tool that tracks the QoE (Quality of Experience) of calls. Can someone please tell me what is "Location" in Agora.io analytics? Where does the location come from and how is it captured.

Answer (score 0):

The "Location" in Agora.io Analytics shows where the actual user makes the call. For example, if a user uses your app to make a call in Seattle, it will show Seattle.

Comment: The data is fetched on IP address

Comment: Thanks a lot Shotclosefire. However in the Same Call List One location shows Singapore while all others are Delhi. Delhi is the place from where the call was made.